# How do I set the depth of images in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I set the depth of different images in ActionScript?

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure if OP is referring to the bit depth - might be the position of the image in display list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring depth as in the position of the image in it's parent's display list, checkout [setChildIndex()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex()) and `swapChildren()` methods of the `DisplayObjectContainer` class.